# Client Side Form validation AND routing using Laravel Collective, Bootstrap Model, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4, routes

I want to create a better web entry system for a small business I am currently helping.

I decided to go with Laravel, as I've used it before, and to intially get going, have created a simple Employee form (using Laravel Collective) that asks for certain Employee fields. E.g Name, Age, Gender, Department, Office, etc.

Now, I wanted to make the Employee profile a "slowly changing dimension". Meaning that, if the user decides to change *certain* fields, in the Blade Edit view, instead of just hitting the submit button, and letting the Update controller, validate and update the records. Is there a way, where in the Edit view itself:

If say, it detects that the Department or Office fields change, that when the user hits the submit button, a can display a short message (in a popup Bootstrap Modal, or something similar), that says:

"We've noticed that the Employee's 'Department', and 'Office' attributes have changed. If this is a correction of a previous error to the current record, please click the 'Edit Current Record' button. (the controller will update the current record, which I know how to do). If this is a genuine change to the employee's profile, please click the 'Update Employee Profile' button (the button would then go to a different function in the controller, that creates a NEW RECORD for that employee, and marks the newly created record's 'current_flag' status to 'Yes', and their old record's 'current_flag' status to 'No)

Secondly, similar to all this. Is there a way I can include client side verification of form fields (using javascript or within laravel collective system), to check for required fields, or a data field being on or after another date field. Something like that. Before the controller function does it's checks.

Please let me know if I'm thinking about the above in the right way, whether this stuff is even possible in Laravel, or whether I should be using a different software that is better at this. Since I've just begun / am in the very early learning stages, I'd rather test this out and get this right now, than build something that can't be scaled or won't work later.

Many thanks in advance!

Sachin

Comment: That could be done with something like Vue.js. That is a js framework and it is already highly integrated in Laravel. Maybe ask this question in the javascript section.

Comment: Arh, sorry... I can see you already tagged it as a js question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything you mentioned is doable and pretty common. However, since this is a very broad question, I can't be more specific.

For you first question you could do as you say: show a popup with the question and based on the user's selection send your request to a different API endpoint. So, for example, if the user decides to update a record, you send the request to `/user/update` and so on.

As for the second question, yes it's very common to have both client side and server side validation. However, that means you have to write the same code twice, which can get old very fast (especially if you have a lot of forms).
A lot of people only have server-side validation and just display the errors to the client. Plus, you should always rely ONLY on the server-side validation before saving data to the database.

That being said, as Ulric McArdle mentioned in the comments, VueJS is a very popular framework for the front-end and there are numerous resources out there on how to integrate it with Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just figuring out where and how to start. I'm looking for some Vue JS that would compare the value of the fields when the edit form is loaded, then compare the value of the fields when the submit button is pressed, and display the appropriate messaging, and routing buttons, in a pop up. (and Vue JS for some basic client side validation - maybe you can't use laravel collective syntax for this). If you know of any specific resources of websites that already do this. Would be grateful. I'm the concept of a record that is "slowly changing" is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to include validation in the form itself, using the following syntax.

```
<div class ="form-group">
   {!! Html::decode(Form::label('first_name','<strong>First Name:</strong>')) !!}
  {{Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), ['class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid': ''), 'placeholder' => '', 'required'])}}
</div>
```

But don't quite fully understand what this bit does:

```
.($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid': '')
```

I already have a 'required' parameter at the end of the array.

I just copied in the above code that I found after researching online, but it's part of the code I don't fully understand.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the solution? Why are you asking us for ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a question to ask for ideas. It was a question to ask what this specific part of the code meant: .($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid': ''). Thanks

Comment: Then maybe you should create a new question if you have another question. When you put additional questions in your solutions it's difficult to understand what you are proposing.

Comment: sure. I'll add another question!